# How to get the ordering of a Django model query set?

Tags: django

`view_set.get_queryset().query.order_by` will get you the ordering tuple of a `ViewSet` class in Django REST Framework, but `ModelName.objects.get_queryset().query.order_by` is always an empty tuple. How come it's not populated? I can see from the database logs that the query is ordered when running `ModelName.objects.all()`. I've also tried to run the actual query, in case the ordering is populated lazily, but even that does not work:

```
>>> all = ModelName.objects.all()
>>> for instance in all:
...     True
>>> all.query.order_by
()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This bit](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5a4d7285bd10bd40d9f7e574a7c421eb21094858/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py#L274-L282) of the internals of the SQL compiler might help. It looks like the ordering information is stored in several different places depending on where it is defined, to allow for overriding at different levels:

```
if self.query.extra_order_by:
    ordering = self.query.extra_order_by
elif not self.query.default_ordering:
    ordering = self.query.order_by
elif self.query.order_by:
    ordering = self.query.order_by
elif self.query.get_meta().ordering:
    ordering = self.query.get_meta().ordering
    self._meta_ordering = ordering
```

`query.order_by` is only set when the queryset is explicitly ordered. If you're relying on default ordering defined on the model class, this will be stored in `query.get_meta().ordering`.